# Spark 2.3 Memory leak with Large SparkSQL Queries

Tags: apache-spark

Running a CDH 5.14.4 cluster along with Spark 2.3 Release 4 CDS. While submitting a fairly large Spark SQL job from a spark application(client mode) , facing some java.lang.OutOfMemoryError errors on few executors. The error is agnostic of the underlying data volumes as i am able to see this error both with 100 or 1 million records. The SQL is quite bulky as it execute a large number of complex conditional statements and expressions.

However when i run the application in local mode instead of yarn as the master , execution goes through smoothly.

Request immediate assistance from the community here.

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
# Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 4505"...
15:20:57.430 [SIGTERM handler] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
15:20:57.435 [Thread-2] INFO org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager - Shutdown hook called
15:20:57.457 [Executor task launch worker for task 13466] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 118.0 in stage 146.1 (TID 13466)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:112)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.logDebug(RuleExecutor.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)


#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
# Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 8562"...
15:21:11.409 [SIGTERM handler] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
15:21:11.420 [Thread-2] INFO org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager - Shutdown hook called
15:21:11.454 [Executor task launch worker for task 13470] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 129.0 in stage 146.1 (TID 13470)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.scala:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.$times(StringLike.scala:71)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.$times(StringOps.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:112)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.logDebug(RuleExecutor.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:134)
```

Comment: It's hard to reproduce a memory leak like this with no minimum reproducable and complete example. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @eliasah Please do not vote to close this question, it seems the similar problem faced all techies are facing so ,it will be better if someone try to provide few points that can avoid this kind of memory leak.

Comment: Like I said, please provide a reproducible example so we can try to help. Otherwise, this isn’t salvageable.

Comment: Memory leak is usually treated by ppl who works and develop the project, in occurrence it’s Spark here.

Comment: It occurs only when query is big,and for other scenario,it works correctly.I also facing same kind of problem. @Guru please provide information about your case.

Comment: @eliasah .. Running a spark sql query on a 6 node cluster (CDH 5.16) with each node having 64GB RAM and 16 cores. spark.executor.instances = 12 ,spark.executor.cores =5 and spark.executor.memory = 12g. The SQL itself is voluminous as each expression  has a lot of CASE WHEN  .. THEN () like statements embedded within it. Interestingly the same query works perfectly on Spark 2.3.0 HDInsight Cluster.

Comment: @eliasah This question can be marked as closed. This issue turned out be a mismatch in spark/hadoop jars between driver (client application ) and executors (yarn.staging.dir). Error was misleading.

Comment: That's why I've asked for a MVCE in the first place. Creating MVCE helps you debug your problems before we even start to take a look of at.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

update : This question can be marked as closed. This issue turned out be a mismatch in spark/hadoop jars between driver (client application ) and executors (yarn.staging.dir). Error was misleading.